# How to clear text of textfield which is in table when table reload

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am having textfield in table's each cell .so when ever i call table reload i want to clear (nil) textfield text.

thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

n cellForRow: method where you create cell set text of textField

```
cell.yourTextField.text = @"";
```

Answer (score -1):

in cellForRow: method where you create cell set text of textField to nil:

```
cell.yourTextField.text = nil;
```